# how to send query string parameters in XMLHttpRequest to php page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have following php variable of name

```
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    <script>
    pge = '<?php echo $name ;?>';        
    var url = "searchCustomerByNameApi2.php"
    //some code 
   xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
```

how can I send pge variable along with url as aquery string and access it on the php page ??

Comment: Try `"searchCustomerByNameApi2.php?pge="+pge` and get it on php page like `$_REQUEST['pge']`.

Comment: thanks a lot it works

Comment: Added this as answer, please accept and upvote, if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Simple you have your javascript code look like this.

```
<script>

   var  name  = '';

   name = '<?php print $_POST["name"]?>';   
   var url = "searchCustomerByNameApi2.php?name"+name;
   xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
   xhttp.send(); 

</script>
```

and php code look like searchCustomerByNameApi2.php page

```
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `"searchCustomerByNameApi2.php?pge="+pge` and get it on php page like `$_REQUEST['pge']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to create a query string from an object:

And append that result to your url:

```
$name=$_POST["name"];

<script>
function encodeQueryData(data) {
   let ret = [];
   for (let d in data)
          ret.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
   return ret.join('&');
 }

pge = '<?php echo $name ;?>'; 
var data = {pge: pge};
var query =encodeQueryData(data);       
var url = "searchCustomerByNameApi2.php";
url += "?" +query;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below?

```
var url = "searchCustomerByNameApi2.php";
var test = "name=<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>";

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send(test);
```

Hope this resolve your issue.